# Simple TicTacToe. Program is in Infinite Loop

Tags: c++, loops, visual-c++

For school I am required to make a TicTacToe console program that has the computer choose a random place to set its "o".

I have tried different things (switch case statements, if else statements, checking and rechecking my functions) however,after the human player makes his second move, the computer will not make any moves, which in my program, causes the "Make your move" printed line repeat indefinitely.

I have tried and tried again to solve it, but I am only a beginner (just started this month.) Please help!

Here is my code:

```
 // Tic_Tac_Toe.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}

// Tic Tac Toe, by Your Name

// Include the libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

//Use the standard namespace
using namespace std;

// Declare global variables
char Board[9];

// Declare functions
void showBoard ( );
bool moveIsValid (int m);
int whoWon ( ); // Returns 0 if no one has won, 1 if player 1 has won, and 2 if player 2 has won

void main ( )
{
    // Seed the rand function
    srand(time(NULL));

   // Declare local variables
   string Player_1_Name;
   string Player_2_Name = "Computer";
   int Whose_Turn = 1; // 1 means it's player 1's turn, 2 means it's player 2's turn
   int Move; // Stores where the player wants to move
   int totalMoves = 0;
   int aiMove = rand () % 10 - 1;


   //Assign values to the playing board
   Board[0] = '0';
   Board[1] = '1';
   Board[2] = '2';
   Board[3] = '3';
   Board[4] = '4';
   Board[5] = '5';
   Board[6] = '6';
   Board[7] = '7';
   Board[8] = '8';

   // Get player names
   cout << "Player 1: Please enter your name." << endl;
   cin >> Player_1_Name;
   cout << "Computer: I will be playing you today." << endl;


   while (whoWon ( ) == 0 && totalMoves < 9)
   {

      // Do this until the player chooses a valid move
      do
      {

         // Show the board
         showBoard ( );

         // Tell which player to move
        switch (Whose_Turn)
        {
        case(1):
            {
            cout << Player_1_Name << " , It's your turn." << endl;
                cin >> Move;
                break;
            }
        case(2):
            {
                cout << Player_2_Name << " , It's your turn." << endl;
                if (aiMove == 0)
                {
                    Move = 0;
                }
                else if (aiMove == 1)
                    Move = aiMove;
            }
        }


      } while (moveIsValid (Move) != true);

      // Add a move to the totalMoves
      totalMoves++;

      // Change whose turn it is
      switch (Whose_Turn)
      {
      case (1):
         {
            Board[Move] = 'x';
            Whose_Turn = 2;
            break;
         }
      case (2):
         {
            Board[Move] = 'o';
            Whose_Turn = 1;
         }
      }
   }

   // Show the board
   showBoard ( );

   //Tell the user who won
   if (whoWon ( ) == 1) 
   {
       cout << Player_1_Name << " has won." << endl;

   }

   else if (whoWon ( ) == 2) 
   {
       cout << Player_2_Name << " has won." << endl;
   }

   else 
   {
       cout <<"It's a tie game!" << endl;
   }
   system("PAUSE");
}

void showBoard ( )
{
   cout << endl;
   cout << Board[0] << " | " << Board[1] << " | " << Board[2] << endl;
   cout << "--+---+--" << endl;
   cout << Board[3] << " | " << Board[4] << " | " << Board[5] << endl;
   cout << "--+---+--" << endl;
   cout << Board[6] << " | " << Board[7] << " | " << Board[8] << endl;
   cout << endl;
}

bool moveIsValid (int m)
{
   if (Board[m] != 'x' && Board[m] != 'o')
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}

int whoWon ( )
{
   if (Board[0] == Board[1] && Board[1] == Board[2])
   {
      if (Board[0] == 'x')
      {
         return 1;
      }
      else
      {
         return 2;
      }
   }
    if (Board[3] == Board[4] && Board[4] == Board[5])
   {
      if (Board[3] == 'x')
      {
         return 1;
      }
      else
      {
         return 2;
      }
   }
     if (Board[6] == Board[7] && Board[7] == Board[8])
   {
      if (Board[6] == 'x')
      {
         return 1;
      }
      else
      {
         return 2;
      }
   }
      if (Board[0] == Board[3] && Board[3] == Board[6])
   {
      if (Board[0] == 'x')
      {
         return 1;
      }
      else
      {
         return 2;
      }
   }
       if (Board[1] == Board[4] && Board[4] == Board[7])
   {
      if (Board[1] == 'x')
      {
         return 1;
      }
      else
      {
         return 2;
      }
   }
        if (Board[2] == Board[5] && Board[5] == Board[8])
   {
      if (Board[2] == 'x')
      {
         return 1;
      }
      else
      {
         return 2;
      }
   }
         if (Board[0] == Board[4] && Board[4] == Board[8])
   {
      if (Board[0] == 'x')
      {
         return 1;
      }
      else
      {
         return 2;
      }
   }
          if (Board[2] == Board[4] && Board[4] == Board[6])
   {
      if (Board[2] == 'x')
      {
         return 1;
      }
      else
      {
         return 2;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint, debug, and post the code where the error is happening

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger? It will surely show you where the possible infinite loop could be.

Comment: How do I set a breakpoint? Where would I put it? Excuse my ignorance, but the only thing I know about breakpoints is that they need to be used after each case statement with the exception of the final case statement. How will setting a breakpoint outside of a case statement help me find the infinite loop?

Comment: @user3338383 Here is a helpful guide for [debugging in visual studio.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your code aiMove variable value is not changing.
That's why code:

```
if (aiMove == 0)
{
Move = 0;
}
else if (aiMove == 1)
Move = aiMove;
}
```

is never executed and Move value does not changes.
There are two problems in your logic:
First, following code generates aiMove value only once.
You should place it in while loop

```
int aiMove = rand () % 10 - 1;
```

Second, its not always true that remainder will come either 0 or 1 only, so your code

```
 if (aiMove == 0)
{
Movee = 0;
}
else if (aiMove == 1)
Move = aiMove;
}
```

should be modified to :

```
if (aiMove == 0)
{
Move = 0;
}
else if (aiMove != 0)
Move = aiMove;
}
```

Then, your code will work fine,. Try following:

```
while (whoWon ( ) == 0 && totalMoves < 9)
{
   system("CLS");
   aiMove = rand () % 10 - 1;
   // Do this until the player chooses a valid move
  do
   {
      // Show the board
       showBoard ( );
          // Tell which player to move
          switch (Whose_Turn)
           {
             case(1):
              {
                 cout << Player_1_Name << " , It's your turn." << endl;
                 cin >> Move;
                 break;
               }
             case(2):
              {
                cout << Player_2_Name << " , It's your turn." << endl;
                 if (aiMove == 0)
                 {
                     Move = 0;
                  }
                 else if (aiMove != 0)
                    Move = aiMove;
               }
                  break;
            }
         } while (moveIsValid (Move) != true);
```

method system("CLS"); will clear your screen after every move and you will see only one board insteade of seeing multiple(as it is happening in current case).

Now your code will be clean.Hope this helps

Comment: Can I tell you something? I love you to death. Thank you, I knew it was something with the do() and with() loops, but had no idea what it was. I appreciate it to the max. Thanks again.

Comment: "aiMove = rand () % 10 - 1;"
This sets aiMove to a value between -1 and 8. So it seems that the AI will never be able to choose square #9 (at the bottom-right). In addition, moveIsValid(m) will sometimes be called with m==-1, which will access Board[-1], which could cause a crash, or at least create a confusing bug.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles : Value required to choose square#9 is 8, and values generated by aiMove = rand () % 10 - 1 are between -1 to 8 so AI is able to choose that square(I have checked all possibilities).    Thanks for the heads up of negative value.Changing if loop in isMove valid to if (Board[m] != 'x' && Board[m] != 'o' && !(Borad[m] < 0 ))
will do the trick(now code will not stumble on crash course for that)..cheers :)

Comment: @user3338383 Please change the definition of method isMove valid so that your code is bug free...

Answer (score 0):

You're not resetting your aiMove variable each turn so moveIsValid is returning false which in turn satisifes the while loop condition resulting in an infinite loop of repeating ai moves.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, everything happens in `int main()`, so you might not want to have it void. Second of all, you have appeared to use the template for a console application `int t_main()`, which, since you don't seem to need command-line arguments, should be removed. Third of all, your function which allows the AI to move never breaks. Also, there were some minor formatting issues that were getting in your way.